How to create raw sockets for TCP and UDP protocols in Windows system?
I encountered many problems while trying to build raw socket packets in Windows using C++, so I consulted some materials.
Because the Windows system restricts developers from using raw sockets to prevent certain types of DDoS attacks, it is not as convenient as the Linux system to build packets from the raw sockets they want. So, how can we create a raw socket that is as convenient as the Linux system to build packets from the raw sockets we want?
refence: TCP/IP raw sockets
The following is a raw socket example implemented in Python language, which works properly on Linux systems but not on Windows systems.
import struct
import socket
import random

def create_radnom_ipv4_addr():
    return '.'.join([f'{random.randint(0x00, 0xff)}' for _ in range(4)])

def send_syn(source_addr :str = None, source_port :int = None, target_addr :str = None, target_port :int = None):
    if not source_addr:
        source_addr = create_radnom_ipv4_addr()
    if not source_port:
        source_port = random.randint(0x0001, 0xffff)

    ip_header = struct.pack(
        '!BBHHHBBH4s4s',
        0x45,
        0x00,
        0x0028,
        0x0000,
        0x4000,
        0x40,
        0x06,
        0x0000,
        socket.inet_aton(source_addr),
        socket.inet_aton(target_addr)
    )

    tcp_header = struct.pack(
        '!HHLLBBHHH',
        source_port,
        target_port,
        0x00000000,
        0x00000000,
        0x50,
        0x02,
        0x0000,
        0x0000,
        0x0000
    )

    packet = ip_header + tcp_header

    raw_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
    raw_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    raw_socket.sendto(packet, (target_addr, target_port))
    raw_socket.close()


The link you posted already answers all your questions.  Does your winsock service support raw packets (use the command in the link to find out).

why is there a c++ tag and no python ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Because the OP is asking how to accomplish this task in C++. The Python is just an example.

As you already noted in your question:

Windows system restricts developers from using raw sockets

So, to answer your question:

how can we create a raw socket that is as convenient as the Linux system to build packets from the raw sockets we want?

Use of RAW sockets on Windows is simply more restricted than on Linux, so is less convenient.  And this is documented on the page you linked to, for instance:

Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.


TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.

That is just the way RAW sockets work on Windows. There is nothing you can do about it with Microsoft's default socket provider. If you need more access, then you'll likely have to write your own socket provider.  Or, use a 3rd party socket stack instead of Winsock.  Or, use WinPCap to send packets.
